# Javascript detection of chrome custom tabs

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chrome-custom-tabs

Looking for the following: anything useful in determining if the current page was loaded via chrome custom tabs. Any browser property, user agent, and or function that will tell a user that they're in a chrome custom tab instance with pure JavaScript.

I know this is a long shot, but any insight is appreciated. Not seeing much on the chrome page: https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/customtabs

Comment: When you launch the app, can't you pass in a query string specifying how you are calling it?

Comment: Launching the chrome tabs/app isn't controlled by me.. This is more of a third party in this context

Comment: Hello. Have you figured out this problem? I really need solution to that and can't find it